# How to configure Eclipse-RCP with Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, eclipse-rcp, h2, tomcat8

I have an Eclipse RCP(E4) application, which I can start without any problem. Now I decide to connect it to my Spring-Boot embedded Tomcat-server. The Spring-Boot-container runs an H2 as an in memory DB. Running Spring-Boot as "Java Application", I access the data in the DB via a rest-service over the browser.

The problem is, I actually want to embed the Spring-Boot part in my RCP-application. So once I start the application it will start my embedded Sring-Boot tomcat and I can run my CRUD-operations directly from the RCP-UI.

Has anyone got experience dealing with Eclipse-RCP running with Spring-Boot?

P.S: I chose explicitly to not put any code hier, because I don't have any code problem yet. The applications run separately well. I just haven't no clue how to relate them.

Comment: Did you found any solution? I need the same

Comment: I actually find a solution, which does not fully work yet. At least, I can start the server in the application, even though I get an exception for missing dependencies, which has nothing to do with the fact that it's work. Here is how I proceeded. After building the Spring-Boot application as a jar, I added it in my RCP application class path and start "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(new String[] {});" in the LifeCycleManager class... But as I said before, it starts the server but I'm having a dependency exception. I'm still trying to figure that out.